# why does the screen on my phone turns white when it detects the target?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm new to augmented reality, and I'm using vuforia 4.2.3 and unity 5, I followed all the steps trying to make a test run and whenever the camera detects the target the whole screen turn white, I've tried many thing but none of them worked, can someone help me?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, SO readers are not psychic and are unable to astral project in front of your computer screen.  It would be jolly good if you could post a code snippet. This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the free sarcasm! that seem to have solved the problem... I'm new to this and I don't know what part of the code would be needed or where to find it..

Comment: As a new user you should have gone through the SO introductory pages which would have explained the recommendations for this site.  I was merely suggesting in a light-hearted way, but alas humour can be subjective. In the meantime - _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_.   _"I followed all the steps trying to make a test run"_ - can you **provide a link** to that please.  That not only shows **prior research** but also helps us when say we may not be experienced with _vuforia 4.2.3_.  This will help us help you

Comment: Also _"I've tried many thing"_ doesn't help us much.  Exactly _what_ did you try?

Comment: Check your `lighting`? Which way is it facing, relative to the `Image Target`? Try turning the target a little to see if it fades?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem that sounds similar.

There is a known bug that causes white screen, could be related to that? See [here for more info](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/issues-and-bugs/white-screen-when-found-target-some-android-devices).

What worked for me was to change the VideoBackground.shader code, as described on that thread.

Go to *Project>>Qualcomm Augmented reality>>Shaders*

Double-click VideoBackground.  This opens up Mono.

In the code, change where it says:

*"queue"="geometry-11"*

to this:

*"queue"="Geometry"*

Save, rebuild etc.

Worked for me.